# import cv2 failing on anaconda virtualenv on OSX

Tags: python, macos, opencv, installation, anaconda

I know this question is old but first I'm on OSX and second whatever I tried so far did not work.

I have created the following environment:

```
name: myenv
channels:
    - defaults
    - menpo
    - conda-forge
dependencies:
    - python=3.6
    - pip
    - pip:
        - python-dateutil==2.8.1
        - python-engineio==3.1.2
        - python-socketio==3.0.0
        - eventlet==0.23.0
        - flask==1.1.2
        - flask-socketio==3.0.1
        - numpy
        - matplotlib
        - jupyter
        - pillow
        - scikit-learn
        - scikit-image
        - scipy
        - h5py
        - seaborn
        - pandas
        - ffmpeg
        - imageio
        - tensorflow==2.4.*
        - keras
        - moviepy
        - opencv-python
        - requests
        - PyDot
        - GraphViz
```

and activated.

Although there is the dependency `opencv-python`, when doing `python3 -c "import cv2"`, I get the error

> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1-mod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 5, in 
> from .cv2 import *
> ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1-mod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/dav1d/lib/libdav1d.4.dylib
> Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib
> Reason: image not found

Any suggestion?

Comment: just to be sure you enter this as `python3 -c "import cv2" ` with quotes ?

Comment: have you activated your environment  before running the command?

Comment: Yes sorry, I corrected...I first noticed the error by launching a script with the line `import cv2`. In the question I just used that because it is shorter. And I have also activated the env.

Comment: Looks like the issue is not with python or cv or conda. The module is correctly found, see your error message referencing `/opt/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1-mod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/init.py`. The issue is with depending libraries. Looks like some part of `ffmpeg` is trying to load from `dav1d`. I would try to reinstall `ffmpeg` and/or `dav1d` (by whichever method you have installed them before)